# App engine app.yaml setting for admin users

Tags: python-2.7, google-app-engine, flask-restful

I was wondering how you can configure your app to restrict certain endpoints to logged in users or even admin users.
Here is my `app.yaml`

```
handlers:
- url: /favicon\.ico
  static_files: favicon.ico
  upload: favicon\.ico

- url: .*
  script: main.app

- url: /admin/.*
  script: main.app
  login: admin
```

However this doesn't work. When visiting any endpoint beginning with `/admin/` I can simply access the url without logging in. Is there any configuration setting that I'm missing?

Comment: Might sound obvious, but have you tried an incognito window? You may already be logged into your Google account.

Comment: Yes, also tried getting the user which is null

Comment: Looking at your app.yaml, does `.*` not take precedence over `/admin/.*`?